# Should class Square publicly inherit from class Rectangle?

Tags: c++, inheritance, public

I find this question very interesting after reading the part of "Effective C++" about public inheritance. Before it would be common sense for me to say yes, because every square **is a** rectangle, but not necessarily other way around. However consider this code:

```
void makeBigger(Rectangle& r) { 

    r.setWidth(r.width() + 10); 

}
```

This code is perfectly fine for a `Rectangle`, but would break the `Square` object if we passed it to `makeBigger` - its sides would become unequal.

---

**So how can I deal with this?**  The book didn't provide an answer (yet?), but I'm thinking of a couple of ways of fixing this:

1. Override `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` methods in `Square` class to also adjust the other side.

   Drawback: code duplication, unnecessary 2 members of `Square`.
2. For `Square` not to inherit from `Rectangle` and be on its own - have `size`, `setSize()` etc.

   Drawback: weird - squares are rectangles after all - it would be nice to reuse `Rectangle`'s features such as right angles etc.
3. Make `Rectangle` abstract (by giving it a pure virtual destructor and defining it) and have *a third class* that represents rectangles that are not squares and inherits from `Rectangle`. That will force us to change the above function's signature to this:

   `void makeBigger(NotSquare& r);`

   Can't see any drawbacks except having an extra class.

---

Is there a better way? I'm leaning towards the third option.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem

Comment: Thanks for the link, it would be great to see some feedback on my attempts though.

Comment: Why this question is not upvoted 100 times? This question is perfect for SO!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of the key principles in OO design that I find gets handled incorrectly.  Mr Meyer does an excellent job of of discussing it the book you are referring to.

The trick is to remember that the principles must be applied to concrete use cases.  When using inheritence, remember that the key is that the "is a" relationship applies to an object when you want to *use that object as a* ...  So whether a square is a rectangle or not depends on what you are going to be doing with rectangles in the future.

If you will be setting width and height of a rectangle independently, then no, a square is not a rectangle (in the context of your software) although it is mathematically.   Thus you have to consider what you will be doing with your base objects.

In the concrete example you mention, there is a canonical answer.  If you make makeBigger a virtual member function of rectangle, then each one can be scaled in a way that is appropriate to a class.  But this is only good OO design if all the (public) methods which apply to a rectangle will apply to a square.

So let's see how this applies to your efforts so far:

1. I see this kind of thing in production code pretty often.  It's excusable as a kludge to fix a gap in an otherwise good design, but it is not desirable.  But it's a problem because it leads to code which is syntactically correct, but semantically incorrect.  It will compile, and do something, but the meaning is incorrect.  Lets say you are iterating over a vector of rectangles, and you scale the width by 2, and the height by 3.  This is semantically meaningless for a square.   Thus it violates the precept "prefer compile time errors to runtime errors".
2. Here you are thinking of using inheritance in order to re-use code.  There's a saying "use inheritance to *be* re-used, not to re-use".  What this means is, you want to use inheritance to make sure the oo code can be re-used elsewhere, as its base object, without any manual rtti.  Remember that there other mechanisms for code re-use:  in C++ these include functional programming and composition.

   If square's and rectangles have shared code (e.g. computing the area based on the fact that they have right angles), you can do this by composition (each contains a common class).  In this trivial example you are probably better off with a function though, for example:
   compute_area_for_rectangle(Shape* s){return s.GetHeight() * s.GetWidth());} 
   provided at a namespace level.

   So if both Square and Rectangle inherit from a base class Shape, Shape having the following public methods: draw(), scale(), getArea() ..., all of these would be semantically meaningful for whatever shape, and common formulas could be shared via namespace level functions.
3. I think if you meditate on this point a little, you'll find a number of flaws with your third suggestion.

   Regarding the oo design perspective: as icbytes mentioned, if you're going to have a third class, it makes more sense that this class be a common base that meaningfully expresses the common uses.  Shape is ok.  If the main purpose is to draw the objects than Drawable might be another good idea.

   There are a couple other flaws in the way you expressed the idea, which may indicate a misunderstanding on your part of virtual destructors, and what it means to be abstract.  Whenever you make a method of a class virtual so that another class may override it, you should declare the destructor virtual as well (S.M. does discuss this in Effective C++, so I guess you would find this out on your own).  This does not make it abstract.  It becomes abstract when you declare at least one of the methods purely virtual -- i.e. having no implementation
   virtual void foo() = 0; // for example 
   This means that the class in question cannot be instantiated.  Obviously since it has at least one virtual method, it should also have the destructor declared virtual.

I hope that helps.  Keep in mind that inheritence is only one method by which code can be re-used.  Good design comes out of the optimal combination of all methods.

For further reading I highly recommend Sutter and Alexandrescu's "C++ Coding Standards", especially the section on Class Design and Inheritence.  Items 34 "Prefer composition to inheritence" and 37 "Public inheritence is substitutability. Inherit, not to reuse, but to be reused.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out the easier solution is

```
Rectangle makeBigger(Rectangle r)
{
    r.setWidth(r.width() + 10); 
    return r;
}
```

Works perfectly well on squares, and correctly returns a rectangle even in that case.

[edit]
The comments point out that the real problem is the underlying call to `setWidth`. That can be fixed in the same way:

```
Rectangle Rectangle::setWidth(int newWidth) const
{
  Rectangle r(*this);
  r.m_width = newWidth;
  return r;
}
```

Again, changing the width of a square gives you a rectangle. And as the `const` shows, it gives you a new `Rectangle` without changing the existing Rectangle The previous function now becomes even easier:

```
Rectangle makeBigger(Rectangle const& r)
{
    return r.setWidth(r.width() + 10); 
}
```

Comment: Again, there is **nothing** stopping the user from writing a `void makeBigger(Rectangle& r);` that takes a reference

Comment: Of course not. Nor is there anything stopping the user from deriving Circle from Rectangle. The unavoidable fact is that people who write code can make bugs.

Comment: That's different. If I'm the creator of the `Rectangle` and `Square` classes, I have to do all I can to make sure that they are easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly. Now for the purpose of this question, we are considering that the user may (perfectly legally and understandably) call methods of `Rectangle` on a `Square` (like `setHeight()`) - a square **is** a rectangle after all. The function `void makeBigger(Rectangle& r);` is not a bug at all - it's totally normal. My task is to prevent it from doing anything stupid and I suggested 3 valid modifications.

Comment: Your solution doesn't solve the problem - it's merely a guidance to the users. It's like saying "Why should I worry with RAII? Let's let the users deal with raw data and pointers themselves - it's ok because it is unavoidable that people can create code that has bugs!"

Comment: @Oleksiy: What raw data, what pointers? If anything, your solutions (with overridden/virtual methods) require pointers. I'm treating a rectangle as a value here.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I used pointers just to make a point - the users should be able to do whatever they want with an object and it shouldn't be a crime for them to pass a `Square` to a function that takes `Rectangle&`, just like in the example above. It is up to me, the provider of `Rectangle` and `Square` to make sure that they function correctly.

Comment: @Oleksiy: Well, the setup as above achieves that. It makes shapes immutable, and transformations create new shapes. Since they're immutable, a user can pass a Square to a function which wants a Rectangle, and know that the Square remains square.

Comment: Ok, but I don't really follow, if I pass a Square of size 10*10, wouldn't `setWidth` return a Rectangle of size 10*20?

Comment: Oh, I get it, it's basically disallowing object modification! Thanks, I like this idea

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `Square` **to be a** `Rectangle`, it should publicly inherit from it. However, this implies that any public methods that work with a `Rectangle` must be appropriately specialised for a `Square`. In this context

```
void makeBigger(Rectangle& r)
```

should not be a standalone function but a virtual member of `Rectangle` which in `Square` is overridden (by providing its own) or hidden (by  `using makeBigger` in the `private` section).

---

Regarding the issue that some things you can to do a `Rectangle` cannot be done to a `Square`. This is a general design dilemma and C++ is not about design. If somebody has a reference (or pointer) to a `Rectangle` that actually is a `Square` and want to do an operation that makes no sense for a `Square`, then you must deal with that. There are several options:

1 use public inheritance and make `Square` throw an exception if an operation is attempted that is not possible for a `Square`

```
struct Rectangle {
  double width,height;
  virtual void re_scale(double factor)
  { width*=factor; height*=factor; }
  virtual void change_width(double new_width)       // makes no sense for a square
  { width=new_width; }
  virtual void change_height(double new_height)     // makes no sense for a square
  { height=new_height; }
};

struct Square : Rectangle {
  double side;
  void re_scale(double factor)
  { side *= factor; }                               // fine
  void change_width(double)
  { throw std::logic_error("cannot change width for Sqaure"); }
  virtual void change_height(double)
  { throw std::logic_error("cannot change height for Sqaure"); }
};
```

This really is awkward and not appropriate if `change_width()` or `change_height()` are integral parts of the interface. In such a case, consider the following.

2 you can have one `class Rectangle` (which may happen to be square) and, optionally, a separate `class Square` that can be converted (`static_cast<Rectangle>(square)`) to a `Rectangle` and hence act as a Rectangle, but not be modified like a `Rectangle`

```
struct Rectangle {
  double width,height;
  bool is_square() const
  { return width==height; }
  Rectangle(double w, double h) : width(w), height(h) {}
};

// if you still want a separate class, you can have it but it's not a Rectangle 
// though it can be made convertible to one
struct Square {
  double size;
  Square(Rectangle r) : size(r.width)   // you may not want this throwing constructor
  { assert(r.is_square()); }
  operator Rectangle() const            // conversion to Rectangle
  { return Rectangle(size,size); }
};
```

This option is the correct choice if you allow for changes to the `Rectangle` that can turn it into a `Square`. In other words, if your `Square` **is not a** `Rectangle`, *as implemented in your code* (with independently modifiable width and height). However, since `Square` can be statically cast to a `Rectangle`, any function taking an `Rectangle` argument can also be called with a `Square`.

Comment: I'm a little confused, could you please rephrase/explain this: "standalone function by a virtual member of `Rectangle` which is overridden"

Comment: @Oleksiy sorry, typo. removed

Comment: You can't stop a user from writing another `makeBigger` function, and if they do, they're able to call any methods on the `Rectangle`. What if they call `setWidth()`? The problem is not about `virtual` functions, the problems is that some parts of `Rectangle` interface do not work properly for a `Square`

Comment: Last sugegstion misses the point: `Square s; Rectangle &r = s; r.makeBigger()` works even if `Square` had hidden `makeBigger`. The suggestion of making it `virtual` does work.

Comment: As Spacemoose said making makeBigger () virtual is a good solution only if all the (public) methods which apply to a rectangle will apply to a square

Answer (score 0):

Except from having an extra class there are no serious drawbacks of your 3rd solution (called also [Factor out modifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem#Factor_out_modifiers)). The only I can think of are:

- Suppose I have a derived Rectangle class with one edge being a half of the other, called for example HalfSquare. Then according to your 3rd solution I'd have to define one more class, called NotHalfSaquare.
- If you have to introduce on more class then let it be rather Shape class both Rectangle, Square and HalfSquare derive from

Comment: No, you would just make your `HalfSquare` inherit from `NotSquare`, that's all

Comment: And what I'd get calling makeBigger() on HalfSquare then?

Comment: It would do exactly what it's doing now - increase the width. This has nothing to do with squares

Comment: If you have to introduce a new class, isn't it better to be a Shape, both Rectangle (your NotSquare) and Square derive from?

Comment: No, because theoretically any `Square` **is a** `Rectangle`. Why introduce an extra class `Shape`? It's like saying "let's have an `Object` class that both `Person` and `Student` derive from, when clearly you need `Student` to inherit from `Person`

Comment: @Oleksiy, in fact, the only drawback of your 3rd solution is this extra class. But you are aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

You say: "because every square is a rectangle" and here the problem lies exactly. Paraphrase of famous Bob Martin's quote:

> The relationships between objects are not shared by their
>   representatives.

(original explanation here: http://blog.bignerdranch.com/1674-what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle/)

So surely every square is a rectangle, but this doesn't mean that a class/object representing a square "is a" class/object representing a rectangle.

The most common real-world, less abstract and intuitive example is: if two lawyers struggle in the court representing a husband and a wife in the context of a divorce, then despite the lawyers are representing the people during a divorce and being currently married  they are not married themselves and are not during a divorce.

Comment: I fail to see how this is a useful analogy. A class *representing* a thing/concept, and a lawyer *representing* a client - those two situations don't really have too much in common, even if you use the same word to describe them.

Comment: They have enough in common - instances of classes contain description of real-world object properties, but are not the object itself. Lawyers represent some "properties" of their clients (their interests), but are not the clients themselves. And this causes that relationships are not transferred between domain of real objects and domain of representatives. I've added a link to a more detailed explanation and the source of the quote. Let me know if that's better.

Answer (score -3):

My idea:
You have a superclass, called Shape. Square inherits from Shape. It has the method resize(int size ). A Rectangle is ClassRectangle, inheriting from Shape but implementing interface IRecangle. IRectangle has method resize_rect(int sizex, int size y ).

In C++ interfaces are created by the usage of so called pure virtual methods. It is not fully well implemented like in c# but for me this is even better solution than third option. Any opinions ?

Comment: So you say `Square` implements `ISquare`, which has a method `resize_rect(x,y)`. If you call this method though, the `Square` is no longer a square, so how exactly does this solve the problem?

Comment: Edited it, sorry, my fault. Should be IRectangle.

Comment: I think you still have a typo, because right now you are saying that Rectangle inherits from Square.

Comment: Right rectangle inherits from square.
Because rectangle can be a square for sure.
But not vice versa.

Comment: @icbytes you're breaking my universe here :) Think about what you just said

Comment: ouuuups, did i juist say that ?
I meant that square is the base of rectangle, the class rectangle still allows to create a square. But it also extends to create rectangles.
That was my intention.
Perhaps we are talking about the same stuff:You said :. A square is a rectangle   ---- i said rectangle can be a square --- and not vice versa and You said rectangle may not be a square----- ... no, i think a rectangle can be a square ( squareshaped ) .... and a square CANNOT be a rectangle ( rectangle shaped ) , i suppose giving my points back.

Comment: Since that was unclear, let me rephrase what I meant: A rectangle might not be a square (as in: there are rectangles that aren't squares), but every square is a rectangle. You say: "and a square CANNOT be a rectangle ( rectangle shaped )", and that's simply not true! Rectangle means "four 90 deg angles", and a square has that. Hence, every square IS a rectangle (mathematically at least. See the current top answer for a discussion of whether that should also hold for this OO design question).

Comment: We are debating this, because a square is described by ONE size parameter. And a recangle by one OR TWO.
As I said, this gets almost philosophically.
From the pure definition a rectangle could be squareshaped but a square could not be rectangle-shaped-----as long the rectangle is described by two different size parameters. ---  though wiki says , that a square is a special case of rectangle----- hmmmm....

Comment: I think we're working with different definitions - or a language barrier - somehow, so the 'what is a rectangle?' discussion probably won't arrive anywhere. Anyways, I can't take back my downvote as long as this answer says that `Square` should be the *base* of `Rectangle`. Think about a `vector<Square*> mySquareVector` - if `Square` was the base of `Rectangle`, you could have a `Rectangle*` in there that points to a non-square rectangle. And surely you agree that having something that isn't a square in `mySquareVector` is absurd.

Comment: now we are talking on better facts.
Right, this is possible in this case. Because of the inheritance this is possible. And therefore i see, that my interface idea also has its culprits.

Comment: @icbytes This philosophical matter has been solved many years ago - please refer to my answer ;)